# Integrate Roblox CAPTCHA into external website

Tags: javascript, python, captcha, 2captcha

I need some help to integrate Roblox CAPTCHA verification into an external website, much like how services such as 2Captcha operate. The aim is to solve Roblox CAPTCHAs by an actual person through an external website.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://client-api.arkoselabs.com/v2/476068BF-9607-4799-B53D-966BE98E2B81/api.js"
        data-callback="render" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function render(enforcement) {
            enforcement.setConfig({
                selector: ".fun-captcha",
                onCompleted: (response) => {
                    window.captchaSolved = true;
                },
                mode: "inline"
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="fun-captcha"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, it replies with:

```json
{"error":"DENIED ACCESS"}
```